# Create an action that filters one sheet and inverse filters another in Tableau from the same selection

Tags: filter, filtering, tableau-api

I have a dashboard set up on which are a series of retail locations.

My filter is different stores/brands so the user clicks on a brand and on one map it shows which locations have that particular store.

My problem is how to set up the filter so that it shows on one map in which retail locations there are stores and on the other the retail locations where there are **not** stores - all on one click.

Answer (score 1):

On the worksheet you want to invert the filter, simply check the exclude mark on the filter menu

[image]

Leave the normal filter worksheet unchanged.